# How set character limit to max. of 30 characters?

Tags: plsql

I am having a bit of an issue in our code. 
There is a procedure that creates a dynamic trigger. 
However, it creates a cursor that is longer then 30 characters. 
I know what variable is making those cursors.

Does anyone know a way to limit the characters to a max. of 30? 
 
Like, if this variable is longer then 30 characters, then cut it off. 
I could find an expample, so I hope that is even possible.

Comment: Please provide the code where this occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chop off characters with `substr(variable, 1, 30)`.

For instance:

```
declare 
   cursor_name varchar(100);
begin
   cursor_name := '012345678901234567890123456789ABCDE';
   cursor_name := substr(cursor_name, 1, 30);
   dbms_output.put_line(cursor_name);
end;
```

... will output:

> 012345678901234567890123456789

Comment: Oh yes, substr() that was it. Thank you.

Comment: I would like to warn about using simple substring.
You can come to situation, where two inputs to your functions differ at 31st char. Trimming it off you come to faulty results. I would much rather revisit the algorithm used to generate names, and calculate value "somehow" - in a way it accepts longer value and produces hash of that text for example. Might be overkill for your setup, but better safe than sorry.